# Check if self is instance of subclass in python

Tags: python, self, isinstance

I have a class called `A`, with two subclasses `B` and `C`. Does the following make sense? Or is there a better way to it?

```
class A():
    ...

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.do_this()
        self.do_that()
        if isInstance(self, B):
            self.do_the_b_stuff()
        elif isInstance(self, C):
            self.do_the_c_stuff()
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a better way to do it: Override `do_stuff` in the child classes.

```
class A:
    def do_stuff(self):
        self.do_this()
        self.do_that()

class B(A):
    def do_stuff(self):
        super().do_stuff()  # call the parent implementation
        self.do_the_b_stuff()

class C(A):
    def do_stuff(self):
        super().do_stuff()  # call the parent implementation
        self.do_the_c_stuff()
```

The advantage of this solution is that the base class doesn't have to know about its child classes - `B` and `C` aren't referenced anywhere in `A`'s body. This makes it easier to add additional subclasses, should that ever be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I appreciate knowing why this is better, and that makes great sense. Thanks for the answer too!